# How I can use Eloquent 5.3 Pagination with Twig

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, herbert

lately I have upgraded my Eloquent to the latest version and the pagination stoped working. Basically when I call the links(), in the twig, to print the pagination I'm getting the following error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function make() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/crm/vendor/illuminate/pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php:140 
Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/crm/vendor/illuminate/pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php(119): Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator->render(NULL) 
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/crm/app/Providers/CMSServiceProvider.php(115): Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator->links() 
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*****/public_html/wp-content/twig-cache/18/189d0df44f1fe623fdad2b6fb631c15897dda3614de070c872657111c85f5f1a.php(333): Herbert\Framework\Application->{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)) 
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/properties-integration/ in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/crm/vendor/illuminate/pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php on line 140
```

Then if I do `dd($clients->links())` inside my controller I'm getting the following error message

```
Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/crm/vendor/illuminate/pagination/AbstractPaginator.php on line 377
```

but if I do `dd($clients)` I'm getting the Eloquent object with the selected records and the current page.

Here are the links of the classes

https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/5.3/LengthAwarePaginator.php#L140-L143

https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/master/AbstractPaginator.php#L405-L424

UPDATE

I did a temporary solution which basically I used the available functions of the AbstractPaginator. If anyone has a better approach please feel free to post it.

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction("render", function ($object) {
    $html = '';
    $data = array(); // start out array
    $data['pages'] = ceil($object->total() / $object->perPage()); // calc pages
    $data['si'] = ($object->currentPage() * $object->perPage()) - $object->perPage(); // what row to start at
    $data['curr_page'] = $object->currentPage(); // Whats the current page

    $max = 7;

    if ($data['curr_page'] < $max) {
        $sp = 1;
    } elseif ($data['curr_page'] >= ($data['pages'] - floor($max / 2))) {
        $sp = $data['pages'] - $max + 1;
    } elseif ($data['curr_page'] >= $max) {
        $sp = $data['curr_page'] - floor($max / 2);
    }

    if ($data['curr_page'] > $max) {
        $html .= '<li ><a href="' . $object->url(1) . '">First Page</a></li>';
    }

    for ($i = $sp; $i <= ($sp + $max - 1); $i++) {

        if ($i > $data['pages']) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($object->currentPage() == $i) {
            $html .= ' <li class="active">';
        } else {
            $html .= '<li >';
        }
        $html .= ' <a href="' . $object->url($i) . '">' . $i . '</a>
                    </li>';

    }

    if ($data['curr_page'] < ($data['pages'] - floor($max / 2))) {
        $html .= '<li ><a href="' . $object->url($object->lastPage()) . '">Last Page</a></li>';
    }

    return $html;

});
```